# Custom Control Breaks Visual Form Inheritance Between Packages

Tags: delphi, package, delphi-xe2, subclass

I'm using Delphi XE2 (Update 3).  I have a very large project, which sometimes crashes the Delphi IDE when I compile a package.  I have been able to strip it down to a simple project that replicates the issue.

### Problem Summary

When you do visual form inheritance between packages using a VCL Frame and the ancestor frame includes a standard control, everything works fine.

When you do the same thing, except you replace the standard control in the ancestor frame with a sub-class of the control, then you can easily crash the Delphi IDE.

All you have to do is compile the package that contains the ancestor frame while viewing a VCL Frame in *Design Mode* that is a member of another package where the VCL Frame descends/inherits from the ancestor frame with a sub-classed control.

I have tried sub-classing both a `TClientDataSet` and a `TEdit`.  Both exhibit the same behavior.

### Question

Why **can't** you use a sub-classed control when doing Visual Form Inheritance between packages when you **can** use the standard controls?

### Steps to Reproduce Problem:

1. Create a folder where all project files can be saved
2. Create files in the folder for each of the **five** files included below
3. Launch Delphi & Close All Files
4. Click "File | New | Other | Delphi Project | Package"
5. Save the package in the folder from step 1 as 'Package1'
6. Add `CDS2.pas` to Package1
7. Build Package1 (add suggested packages)
8. Install Package1 (will register TMyCDS)
9. Add `BaseForm.pas` to Package1 (add suggested VCL framework)
10. Build Package1 (add suggested packages), build again
11. Right-click `ProjectGroup1` and select "Add New Project | Delphi Projects | Package"
12. Save the new package in the folder from step 1 as 'Package2'
13. Add `SecondFrame.pas` to Package2 (add suggested VCL framework)
14. Build Package2 (add suggested packages)
15. View `SecondFrame` in design mode (e.g., Press F12)
16. Save any changes (including the project group because Delphi is about to crash)
17. While viewing the `SecondFrame` in design mode, build **Package1**

The build fails and I get this error:

```
[DCC Error] E2161 Error: RLINK32: Error opening file "C:\[folder]\BaseFrame.dfm"
```

If I **compile** instead of **build** in step 17, it will often compile without errors.  However, sometimes when I then try to re-display `SecondFrame` in design mode, I get this error:

```
Access violation at address 5003C976 in module 'rtl160.bpl'. Read of address FFFFFFC4.

[5003C976]{rtl160.bpl  } System.GetDynaMethod (Line 13480, "System.pas" + 7) + $0
[500ADE1D]{rtl160.bpl  } System.Classes.IsDefaultObjectProp (Line 9525, "System.Classes.pas" + 9) + $B
[500AE2C1]{rtl160.bpl  } System.Classes.IsDefaultPropertyValue (Line 9651, "System.Classes.pas" + 29) + $A
[500AECA7]{rtl160.bpl  } System.Classes.TWriter.WriteProperty (Line 9893, "System.Classes.pas" + 12) + $7
[5044739A]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TScrollingWinControl.IsTouchPropertyStored (Line 3200, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[503432C6]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TCustomTouchManager.IsTabletOptionsStored (Line 17359, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 1) + $9
[500AE08D]{rtl160.bpl  } System.Classes.IsDefaultMethodProp (Line 9606, "System.Classes.pas" + 4) + $4
[500AE0ED]{rtl160.bpl  } System.Classes.IsDefaultMethodProp (Line 9609, "System.Classes.pas" + 7) + $24
[500AE2CC]{rtl160.bpl  } System.Classes.IsDefaultPropertyValue (Line 9653, "System.Classes.pas" + 31) + $A
[5033A7E9]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.GetChildren (Line 12359, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 1) + $3
[5003C9A6]{rtl160.bpl  } System.@CallDynaInst (Line 13519, "System.pas" + 4) + $0
[50447AE1]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TCustomFrame.GetChildren (Line 3450, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 6) + $6
[500AD658]{rtl160.bpl  } System.Classes.TWriter.WriteData (Line 9270, "System.Classes.pas" + 54) + $2
[500B4423]{rtl160.bpl  } System.Classes.TComponent.ValidateRename (Line 12845, "System.Classes.pas" + 0) + $F
[500AD317]{rtl160.bpl  } System.Classes.TWriter.WriteComponent (Line 9200, "System.Classes.pas" + 20) + $9
[500AD761]{rtl160.bpl  } System.Classes.TWriter.WriteFloat (Line 9298, "System.Classes.pas" + 1) + $3
[20FEC1AB]{designide160.bpl} ComponentDesigner.TComponentRoot.CreateRootInstance (Line 2288, "ComponentDesigner.pas" + 24) + $7
[20FEBFD7]{designide160.bpl} ComponentDesigner.TComponentRoot.CreateRootAs (Line 2255, "ComponentDesigner.pas" + 2) + $4
[20FEBEFA]{designide160.bpl} ComponentDesigner.TComponentRoot.CreateFromStream (Line 2235, "ComponentDesigner.pas" + 7) + $9
[20FEEF41]{designide160.bpl} ComponentDesigner.TComponentRoot.Resurrect (Line 3434, "ComponentDesigner.pas" + 11) + $6
[2104F16E]{designide160.bpl} EmbeddedDesignerForm.TFormEditorView.Display (Line 144, "EmbeddedDesignerForm.pas" + 4) + $5
[2075E399]{coreide160.bpl} EditorForm.TEditWindow.ShowView (Line 4294, "EditorForm.pas" + 49) + $F
[20758D44]{coreide160.bpl} EditorForm.TEditWindow.SwitchViews (Line 2147, "EditorForm.pas" + 6) + $9
[2075889A]{coreide160.bpl} EditorForm.TEditWindow.ViewBarChange (Line 1996, "EditorForm.pas" + 2) + $1
[504C0F8D]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Tabs.TTabSet.CanChange (Line 1910, "Vcl.Tabs.pas" + 3) + $9
[504C0FDE]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Tabs.TTabSet.SetTabIndex (Line 1921, "Vcl.Tabs.pas" + 5) + $0
[504C126A]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Tabs.TTabSet.MouseDown (Line 2033, "Vcl.Tabs.pas" + 6) + $2
[50332E54]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.DoMouseDown (Line 7343, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 7) + $2B
[50332EA3]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WMLButtonDown (Line 7354, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 7) + $E
[5033280D]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TControl.WndProc (Line 7204, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 91) + $6
[5033715B]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 9976, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 152) + $6
[5003D4F7]{rtl160.bpl  } System.TMonitor.TryEnter (Line 14786, "System.pas" + 10) + $0
[5003D06C]{rtl160.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Enter (Line 14489, "System.pas" + 4) + $2
[5003CF10]{rtl160.bpl  } System.TMonitor.CheckOwningThread (Line 14411, "System.pas" + 2) + $0
[5003D216]{rtl160.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 14600, "System.pas" + 9) + $7
[5003D24F]{rtl160.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 14614, "System.pas" + 2) + $7
[50313627]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Graphics.FreeMemoryContexts (Line 7043, "Vcl.Graphics.pas" + 12) + $8
[503367B0]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9689, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[503367C5]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9692, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 6) + $0
[503369F0]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.IsControlMouseMsg (Line 9753, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 9) + $25
[5033715B]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 9976, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 152) + $6
[503367B0]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 9689, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[500B6030]{rtl160.bpl  } System.Classes.MakeObjectInstance (Line 13921, "System.Classes.pas" + 0) + $0
[504525E7]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 10164, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
[5045262A]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.HandleMessage (Line 10194, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[5045295D]{vcl160.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Run (Line 10331, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 26) + $3
```

Regardless of what error occurs, when you try to do almost anything else Delphi will throw various random **Access Violations**.  I close Delphi after dismissing the error.  Then I kill BDS.EXE using Task Manager (to avoid many additional A/V errors).

I tried debugging Delphi as follows:

### Debugging:

1. Relaunch Delphi
2. Make sure `SecondFrame` is not open
3. Remove/re-install Package1 and rebuild it
4. Double-click Package1 so it is the active project
5. Set the debug host application to Delphi (*C:\[path]\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\bds.exe*)
6. Run Package1 with debug (F9)
7. Once Delphi opens a second time (in the second instance) make sure your project group is opened and then open `SecondFrame`
8. Make sure `SecondFrame` is in design mode (e.g., press F12) and then **compile** Package1

Sometimes the first instance of Delphi will trap the exception raised in the second instance, sometimes it won't.  When it does, the exception and stack trace look like this:

```
First chance exception at $5003C97D. Exception class $C0000005 with message 'access violation at 0x5003c97d: read of address 0x00000001'. Process bds.exe (8912)

:5003c97d GetDynaMethod + $D
:20fd45a6 TPairings.AddChildren + $46
:20fd4351 TPairing.SetComponent + $2D
:20fed656 TComponentRoot.GetRootStream + $5E
:20ff9d26 TRootStream.Create + $7A
:20ff2704 TComponentRoot.FormFileOpen + $14
:21b4231b ; C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\delphicoreide160.bpl
:204e7a1e ; C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\coreide160.bpl
:20614f2f ; C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\coreide160.bpl
:206150f9 ; C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\coreide160.bpl
:20615173 ; C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\coreide160.bpl
:066d1339 ; C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\dcc32160.dll
:1ac81dea ; C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin\RLINK32.DLL
:2a242a24
```

.

---

Here are the 5 files to use in the **Steps to Reproduce Problem** above:

### BaseFrame.dfm

```
object BaseFrameClass: TBaseFrameClass
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Width = 320
  Height = 240
  TabOrder = 0
  object MyCDS1: TMyCDS
    Aggregates = <>
    Params = <>
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
  end
end
```

### BaseFrame.pas

```
unit BaseFrame;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient, CDS2;

type
  TBaseFrameClass = class(TFrame)
    MyCDS1: TMyCDS;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

### CDS2.pas

```
unit CDS2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient;

type
  TMyCDS = class(TClientDataSet)
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Test', [TMyCDS]);
end;

end.
```

### SecondFrame.dfm

```
inherited SecondFrameClass: TSecondFrameClass
end
```

### SecondFrame.pas

```
unit SecondFrame;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, BaseFrame, Data.DB, Datasnap.DBClient, CDS2;

type
  TSecondFrameClass = class(TBaseFrameClass)
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Comment: +1 For a very thorough question. However, unless you are just after knowledge and an answer to the "why", I think you would need to file a bug report to QC for this to get a resolution.

Comment: I was hoping someone else had a similar problem with the `TClientDataSet` and found a cleaver work around.  But I'm leaning towards your same conclusion -- a QC report...

Comment: Come to think of it, have you tried the same thing with descendants of other "standard" controls? The TClientDataSet involvement may be a red herring?

Comment: Excellent question -- I tried it with only a `TMyEdit = class(TEdit)` (no flavor of `TClientDataSet`) and the result is 100% the same.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate, but what I expected. Visual form inheritance is nice, but has its drawbacks. I have run into a couple of strange problems as well. Changes in ancestors not ending up in descendants depending on either or both being open, that sort of thing. The only "work around" I have found was to ensure that all descendants are closed when editing an ancestor plus not relying on the dfm and setting up forms, frames and controls at run-time. Yes it does take away the visual design features, but is much more reliable.

Comment: Also, I tend to use very ugly and varied background colors at design time for all containers and change their parent background to true at run-time. Makes my forms and frames look like an ugly candybox at design time, but makes any oversight in colors and alignment jump out immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts and for sharing your experience.  It helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with DSPack installation on Delphi XE2. I would swear that it was working to the date. However, after getting AV I tried many ways to fix it.

I finally fixed it after I saw your question which pointed me to the idea that inheritance is messing it up. First I moved everything from base package to design page and then I removed base package from project group, compiled, and installed. Working fine.